# "to+verb" or "verb" only?

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives

From Harper Lee's novel, *To Kill A Mockingbird*:

> Atticus had urged them to accept the state’s generosity in allowing them to plead Guilty to second-degree murder and **escape** with their lives, but they were Haverfords, in Maycomb County a name synonymous with jackass.

There is no *to* before *escape*, but isn't with the usage of *and*, verb should have the same form before and after it?

So it seems more appropriate to be like this:

> **to plead** Guilty *and* **to escape** with lives.

Instead of the original context:

> **to plead** Guilty *and* (no to here) **escape** with lives.

So to use to here or not?

Comment: The *to* is simply ellipted here; it has been left out to avoid repetition.

Comment: I somehow compared it to **He allowed them to eat and drink**. And all is magically fine now.

Comment: Yes, it's essentially the same thing in that sentence. Perhaps you got confused because there are more words in between of the two verbs of your original sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have said, the "to" has been omitted because of repetition. Either version makes sense and both are in common usage but, indeed with a "to" it is grammatically correct.